# facing converting a fragment into an activity

Tags: java, android

when i try to converting an activity than i get following two errors.
**1. `getActivity ()` 2. `getContext(`)** .please convert my code into activity.
my code is bellow.

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment  {
private Button btnA, btnB, btnC, btnD, btnSubmit, btnNext, btnPrev, btnFlag;
private TextView tvQuestion, tvLayout;
private int totalItem;
private int listItem = 0;
private ArrayList<mcqQuestion> quesList = new ArrayList<>();
private int score = 0;
private boolean isLoading = true;
private RelativeLayout rlMcqProgress;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private boolean allAnswered = false;
private RecyclerView rvQuesLayout;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
private QuestionLayoutRecyclerAdapter adapter;
private LinearLayout llQuestionAll;
private FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
private DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("tax").child("Questions");
public TestFragment() {
// Required empty public constructor
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);
btnA = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_mcq_A);
btnB = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_mcq_B);
btnC = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_mcq_C);
btnD = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_mcq_D);
btnSubmit = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_mcq_submit);
btnNext = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_mcq_next);
btnPrev = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_mcq_prev);
btnFlag = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_mcq_flag);
tvQuestion = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_mcq_question);
tvLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_mcq_question_layout);
rvQuesLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.rv_layout_question_test);
rlMcqProgress = view.findViewById(R.id.rl_mcq_progress);
rlMcqProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
llQuestionAll=view.findViewById(R.id.ll_test_all);
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
getFData();
btnA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
quesList.get(listItem).setSelAnswer("optA");
setButtonColor();
btnA.setBackgroundResource(R.color.sky_blue);
}
});
btnB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
quesList.get(listItem).setSelAnswer("optB");
setButtonColor();
btnB.setBackgroundResource(R.color.sky_blue);
}
});
btnC.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
quesList.get(listItem).setSelAnswer("optC");
setButtonColor();
btnC.setBackgroundResource(R.color.sky_blue);
}
});
btnD.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
quesList.get(listItem).setSelAnswer("optD");
setButtonColor();
btnD.setBackgroundResource(R.color.sky_blue);
}
});
btnFlag.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
setFlagValue();
setFlagColor();
}
});
tvLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
if (rvQuesLayout.getVisibility() == View.GONE || rvQuesLayout.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
rvQuesLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
llQuestionAll.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else {
rvQuesLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
llQuestionAll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
}
});
btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
displayNextQues();
}
});
btnPrev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
displayPrevQues();
}
});
btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
for (int i = 0; i < totalItem; i++) {
if (quesList.get(i).getSelAnswer().equals("none")) {
allAnswered = false;
score++;
break;
} else {
if (quesList.get(i).getSelAnswer().equals(quesList.get(i).getAnswer())) {
score++;
}
allAnswered = true;
}
}
if (allAnswered) {
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),finalresult.class);
intent.putExtra("score" , score);
intent.putExtra("questions" , totalItem);
startActivity(intent);
} else {
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Answer all the questions", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

}
});
return view;
}
private void makeRecyclerView() {
layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
//rvQuesLayout.setHasFixedSize(true);
rvQuesLayout.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
adapter = new QuestionLayoutRecyclerAdapter(quesList);
rvQuesLayout.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.setOnItemClickListner(new QuestionLayoutRecyclerAdapter.onItemClickListner() {
@Override
public void onClick(int pos) {
listItem=pos;
if(listItem>=0 && listItem<totalItem){
makeAllDisplay();
rvQuesLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
llQuestionAll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
}
});
}
private void setDisplay(int item) {
btnA.setText(quesList.get(item).getOptA());
btnB.setText(quesList.get(item).getOptB());
btnC.setText(quesList.get(item).getOptC());
btnD.setText(quesList.get(item).getOptD());
tvQuestion.setText(quesList.get(item).getQuestion());


}
private void getFData() {
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
for (DataSnapshot messageSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
String qtext = (String) messageSnapshot.child("qText").getValue();
String optA = (String) messageSnapshot.child("optA").getValue();
String optB = (String) messageSnapshot.child("optB").getValue();
String optC = (String) messageSnapshot.child("optC").getValue();
String optD = (String) messageSnapshot.child("optD").getValue();
String answer = (String) messageSnapshot.child("answer").getValue();
quesList.add(new mcqQuestion(qtext, optA, optB, optC, optD, answer, "none", false));
Log.d("TOTAL ITEM", String.valueOf(quesList.size()));

}
totalItem = quesList.size();
isLoading = false;
if (!isLoading) {
setDisplay(listItem);
rlMcqProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
tvLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
makeRecyclerView();
}
@Override
public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

}
});
}

private void setFlagValue(){
if (quesList.get(listItem).isFlag()) {
quesList.get(listItem).setFlag(false);
} else {
 quesList.get(listItem).setFlag(true);
}
}
private void setFlagColor(){
if (quesList.get(listItem).isFlag()) {
btnFlag.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()), R.color.black));
btnFlag.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()), R.color.grey));
} else {
btnFlag.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()), R.color.grey_light));
btnFlag.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()), R.color.grey));
}
}
private void setButtonColor() {
btnA.setBackgroundResource(R.color.grey_light);
btnB.setBackgroundResource(R.color.grey_light);
btnC.setBackgroundResource(R.color.grey_light);
btnD.setBackgroundResource(R.color.grey_light);
}
private void displayNextQues() {
if (listItem < totalItem - 1) {
listItem++;
makeAllDisplay();
} else {
btnNext.setVisibility(View.GONE);
btnSubmit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
}
private void makeAllDisplay(){
setDisplay(listItem);
setButtonColor();
setFlagColor();
switch (quesList.get(listItem).getSelAnswer()) {
case "optA":
btnA.setBackgroundResource(R.color.sky_blue);
break;
case "optB":
btnB.setBackgroundResource(R.color.sky_blue);
break;
case "optC":
btnC.setBackgroundResource(R.color.sky_blue);
break;
case "optD":
btnD.setBackgroundResource(R.color.sky_blue);
break;
default:
setButtonColor();
break;
}
}
private void displayPrevQues() {
btnNext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
if (listItem > 0 && listItem < totalItem) {
listItem--;
makeAllDisplay();
} else {
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cannot GO back!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
}
```

Comment: Learn about activity, fragment and their lifecycle.  Check the documentation - https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/intro-activities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when i try to converting an activity than i get following two errors. 1. getActivity () 2. getContext()

When you change Fragment to Activity, all method need `getActivity()` and `getContext()` can be change to this. Example `new Intent(getActivity(),finalresult.class);` to `new Intent(this,finalresult.class);`

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    private Button btnA, btnB, btnC, btnD, btnSubmit, btnNext, btnPrev, btnFlag;
    private TextView tvQuestion, tvLayout;
    private int totalItem;
    private int listItem = 0;
    private ArrayList<mcqQuestion> quesList = new ArrayList<>();
    private int score = 0;
    private boolean isLoading = true;
    private RelativeLayout rlMcqProgress;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private boolean allAnswered = false;
    private RecyclerView rvQuesLayout;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private QuestionLayoutRecyclerAdapter adapter;
    private LinearLayout llQuestionAll;
    private FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    private DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("tax").child("Questions");

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_test);
        btnA = findViewById(R.id.btn_mcq_A);
        btnB = findViewById(R.id.btn_mcq_B);
        btnC = findViewById(R.id.btn_mcq_C);
        btnD = findViewById(R.id.btn_mcq_D);
        btnSubmit = findViewById(R.id.btn_mcq_submit);
        btnNext = findViewById(R.id.btn_mcq_next);
        btnPrev = findViewById(R.id.btn_mcq_prev);
        btnFlag = findViewById(R.id.btn_mcq_flag);
        tvQuestion = findViewById(R.id.tv_mcq_question);
        tvLayout = findViewById(R.id.tv_mcq_question_layout);
        rvQuesLayout = findViewById(R.id.rv_layout_question_test);
        rlMcqProgress = findViewById(R.id.rl_mcq_progress);
        rlMcqProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        llQuestionAll = findViewById(R.id.ll_test_all);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        getFData();
        btnA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                quesList.get(listItem).setSelAnswer("optA");
                setButtonColor();
                btnA.setBackgroundResource(R.color.sky_blue);
            }
        });
        btnB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                quesList.get(listItem).setSelAnswer("optB");
                setButtonColor();
                btnB.setBackgroundResource(R.color.sky_blue);
            }
        });
        btnC.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                quesList.get(listItem).setSelAnswer("optC");
                setButtonColor();
                btnC.setBackgroundResource(R.color.sky_blue);
            }
        });
        btnD.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                quesList.get(listItem).setSelAnswer("optD");
                setButtonColor();
                btnD.setBackgroundResource(R.color.sky_blue);
            }
        });
        btnFlag.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setFlagValue();
                setFlagColor();
            }
        });
        tvLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                if (rvQuesLayout.getVisibility() == View.GONE || rvQuesLayout.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
                    rvQuesLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    llQuestionAll.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    rvQuesLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    llQuestionAll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                displayNextQues();
            }
        });
        btnPrev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                displayPrevQues();
            }
        });
        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                for (int i = 0; i < totalItem; i++) {
                    if (quesList.get(i).getSelAnswer().equals("none")) {
                        allAnswered = false;
                        score++;
                        break;
                    } else {
                        if (quesList.get(i).getSelAnswer().equals(quesList.get(i).getAnswer())) {
                            score++;
                        }
                        allAnswered = true;
                    }
                }
                if (allAnswered) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, finalresult.class);
                    intent.putExtra("score", score);
                    intent.putExtra("questions", totalItem);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, "Answer all the questions", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    private void makeRecyclerView() {
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        //rvQuesLayout.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rvQuesLayout.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        adapter = new QuestionLayoutRecyclerAdapter(quesList);
        rvQuesLayout.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.setOnItemClickListner(new QuestionLayoutRecyclerAdapter.onItemClickListner() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(int pos) {
                listItem = pos;
                if (listItem >= 0 && listItem < totalItem) {
                    makeAllDisplay();
                    rvQuesLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    llQuestionAll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void setDisplay(int item) {
        btnA.setText(quesList.get(item).getOptA());
        btnB.setText(quesList.get(item).getOptB());
        btnC.setText(quesList.get(item).getOptC());
        btnD.setText(quesList.get(item).getOptD());
        tvQuestion.setText(quesList.get(item).getQuestion());
    }

    private void getFData() {
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot messageSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String qtext = (String) messageSnapshot.child("qText").getValue();
                    String optA = (String) messageSnapshot.child("optA").getValue();
                    String optB = (String) messageSnapshot.child("optB").getValue();
                    String optC = (String) messageSnapshot.child("optC").getValue();
                    String optD = (String) messageSnapshot.child("optD").getValue();
                    String answer = (String) messageSnapshot.child("answer").getValue();
                    quesList.add(new mcqQuestion(qtext, optA, optB, optC, optD, answer, "none", false));
                    Log.d("TOTAL ITEM", String.valueOf(quesList.size()));

                }
                totalItem = quesList.size();
                isLoading = false;
                if (!isLoading) {
                    setDisplay(listItem);
                    rlMcqProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    tvLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                makeRecyclerView();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void setFlagValue() {
        if (quesList.get(listItem).isFlag()) {
            quesList.get(listItem).setFlag(false);
        } else {
            quesList.get(listItem).setFlag(true);
        }
    }

    private void setFlagColor() {
        if (quesList.get(listItem).isFlag()) {
            btnFlag.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(Objects.requireNonNull(this), R.color.black));
            btnFlag.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(Objects.requireNonNull(this), R.color.grey));
        } else {
            btnFlag.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(Objects.requireNonNull(this), R.color.grey_light));
            btnFlag.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(Objects.requireNonNull(this), R.color.grey));
        }
    }

    private void setButtonColor() {
        btnA.setBackgroundResource(R.color.grey_light);
        btnB.setBackgroundResource(R.color.grey_light);
        btnC.setBackgroundResource(R.color.grey_light);
        btnD.setBackgroundResource(R.color.grey_light);
    }

    private void displayNextQues() {
        if (listItem < totalItem - 1) {
            listItem++;
            makeAllDisplay();
        } else {
            btnNext.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btnSubmit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    private void makeAllDisplay() {
        setDisplay(listItem);
        setButtonColor();
        setFlagColor();
        switch (quesList.get(listItem).getSelAnswer()) {
            case "optA":
                btnA.setBackgroundResource(R.color.sky_blue);
                break;
            case "optB":
                btnB.setBackgroundResource(R.color.sky_blue);
                break;
            case "optC":
                btnC.setBackgroundResource(R.color.sky_blue);
                break;
            case "optD":
                btnD.setBackgroundResource(R.color.sky_blue);
                break;
            default:
                setButtonColor();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void displayPrevQues() {
        btnNext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (listItem > 0 && listItem < totalItem) {
            listItem--;
            makeAllDisplay();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cannot GO back!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget add new Activity to Manifest

Comment: I am beginner can you please convert this properly so that  i just copy paste in my activity .

Comment: ok try it, I already updated